# Jmeter JDBC can't bulk insert

Tags: jmeter

Variables in test plan
Result -  Result_${__time(yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm)}
Result_File_Path - \\test\share\

summary report filename to save in  ${Result_File_Path}${Result}.csv

Tear down thread group JDCB request with update statement

```
DECLARE @currentTime VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(50);
SET @currentTime = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108), ':', '-');
SET @currentTime = '_' + RIGHT('00' + SUBSTRING(@currentTime, 1, 2), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + 
SUBSTRING(@currentTime, 4, 2), 2);
SET @Result = 'Result_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 23)+@currentTime+'.csv'
SET @Path = '\\test\share\'
DECLARE @fullPath NVARCHAR(50) =CONCAT(@Path, @Result)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS JmeterSummaryReport
CREATE TABLE JmeterSummaryReport(
    
average_response_time integer,
sampler_request Varchar(50),
responseCode Varchar(50),
responseMessage VARCHAR(50),
 threadName VARCHAR(50),   
 success VARCHAR(10),
  bytes Integer,
  sentBytes Integer,
  Latency Integer    
)
exec ('BULK INSERT JmeterSummaryReport
FROM ''' + @fullPath + '''
WITH 
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
);
')
```

Summary report file is generated to provided path. The query executes it drops existing table, create empty one but doesn't execute Bulk insert. Where am I wrong

Comment: I found the solution. Set the "Query Type" to "Callable Statement" and use EXEC sp_executesql